# dependency of reports on database

Tags: database, report

I think it is a common issue: you have a large and complex database, and a few hundreds of reports built on top of it. everytime, before the DB schema is changed, someone need to look at the reports to make sure the reports are not affected.

Is there any tools to check the dependency of reports(reporting service) for the database change?

-- update
We are using MS reporting service for the report, and SQL server database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it depends what tools for reporting as well as what database you are using . then i can give u a clue for it

Comment: We are using MS reporting service for the report, and SQL server database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to buy a special tool for it.  SSMS has a nice UI for doing it, or alternatively, you can use one of the catalog views to query all report definitions at once.

Here's an MSDN link with some good samples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677168.aspx